# where does ros get sensor data

Tags: ros, sensor

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In short time of perusing the code it appears ROS expects to get sensor data from sockets. What agent posts the data to the sockets? user space proxy or kernel module (on Linux). For example, I might use a processor that has some ADC converters connected to sensors. The cpu vendor has decided to implement his drivers as either IIO, Input, HID_RAW
drivers or has used some custom solution. I didn't find any references in your code to /sys or /dev devices, but there
is a Python file that loads a program called 'sensors' using the subprocess library module. How can I find the code for this program?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/175607/where-does-ros-get-sensor-data/) by [miltmobley](https://answers.ros.org/users/19048/miltmobley/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-06-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should review the [tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials) on Nodes and Topics.

---

Originally posted by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) with karma: 2962 on 2014-06-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-06-30**:
I think reading the http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Introduction and especially http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Concepts pages first would be a good idea.